# Python DataFrameを使ってデータを置換する方法について

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Python3で `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` を使ってExcelファイルの行と列を入れ替えた後に `Replace` を使ってデータを置換したいです。
実現したい内容が上手くいかないので質問させて頂きます。
ご指導をお願いできますでしょうか。

**Excel Data**

| No | 国 | 都市 | ディズニーランド有/無 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 有 |
|  |  | フロリダ | 有 |
| 2 | フランス | パリ | 有 |
| 3 | 日本 | 東京 | 有 |
|  |  | 沖縄 |  |
|  |  | 京都 | 無 |
| 4 | ブラジル | サンパウロ | 無 |

**実現したいExcelのデータ**

**無しと空白の場合、都市の列を"0"へ置換したいです。**

| No | 国 | 都市 | ディズニーランド有/無 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 有 |
| 1 | アメリカ | フロリダ | 有 |
| 2 | フランス | パリ | 有 |
| 3 | 日本 | 東京 | 有 |
| 3 | 日本 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 日本 | 0 | 無 |
| 4 | ブラジル | 0 | 無 |

下記のコードで0へ置換できますが、毎回データ固定ではないでので、
不定的に変わる時にどのように置換すればよろしいでしょうか。

```
df= df.replace({' ': '0'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'京都': '0'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'サンパウロ': '0'}, regex=True)
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# convert to pandas dataframe
data = ws.values
cols = next(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# fill in the forward
df[['No', '国']] = df[['No', '国']].fillna(method='ffill')
df.No = df.No.astype(int)

# select data
#dfx = df[df['ディズニーランド有/無'] == '無']
# dfx_2 =dfx.replace({dfx: '0'}, regex=True)

df= df.replace({' ': '0'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'京都': '0'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'サンパウロ': '0'}, regex=True)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))

# save to a new sheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
  ws.append(r)

wb.save('testchange.xlsx')
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[pandasで条件に応じて値を代入（where, mask）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-where-mask/), [Pandas/Python: Set value of one column based on value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49161120/9014308)

Comment: 皆さん
早速回答ありがとうございます。先ずは上記の方法で試してます。

Comment: あともう少しできそうですが、こちらコードでやってみましたが変化ないです。'都市'の箇所を変更する必要あると思います。ただどのように変更すればよろしいでしょうか。`dfx = df[df['ディズニーランド有/無'] == '無'].replace({'都市': '0'}, regex=True)`

Comment: `isin` を使うとよいかもしれません。`df.loc[df['ディズニーランド有/無'].isin(('無', '', None)), '都市'] = 0` 「無しと空白の場合」と書かれていますが、実際には `None` となっているかもしれないので `None` も含めています。

Comment: ちなみに「 == '無' 」とか値を列挙して判定するよりも、「 != '有' 」の方が簡単だと思われるのですが、そちらでは駄目なのでしょうか？

Comment: 皆さん、回答ありがとうございます。isinで上手く希望通りの条件で抽出できました。また != '有' でも使ってみます。いろんな意見を頂きありがとうございます。毎日勉強になります。

Answer (score 1):

isinを使って、希望通りの条件抽出できました。
データフレームから条件に合致するデータを抽出出来るようになります。

**変更前**

```
df= df.replace({' ': '0'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'京都': '0'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'サンパウロ': '0'}, regex=True)
```

**変更後**

```
df.loc[df['ディズニーランド有/無'].isin(('無', '', None)), '都市'] = 0
```

参考ページ
[pandasの「isin」の使い方を解説](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-query/)